# How to insert array into MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array that I am trying to insert into my MYSQL database.  I'm not sure if its my MYSQL database or if its my php code but when I open my php file it does not insert anything into my table.  Here is my code I have so far.

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("ms122r_reports", $con); 

    // Filter out zeros
    $words = file('http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/latest_obs/latest_obs.txt',              FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $words = array_map('rtrim',$words);
    $string = implode(" ",$words);
    $array = explode(" ",$string);

    $filtered = (array_filter($array));

    $row4 = array_slice($filtered, 704, 22);

    $var1 = array_slice($row4, 0, 1);
    $var2 = array_slice($row4, 1, 1);
    $var3 = array_slice($row4, 2, 1);
    $var4 = array_slice($row4, 3, 1);
    $var5 = array_slice($row4, 4, 1);
    $var6 = array_slice($row4, 5, 1);
    $var7 = array_slice($row4, 6, 1);
    $var8 = array_slice($row4, 7, 1);
    $var9 = array_slice($row4, 8, 1);
    $var10 = array_slice($row4, 9, 1);
    $var11 = array_slice($row4, 10, 1);
    $var12 = array_slice($row4, 11, 1);
    $var13 = array_slice($row4, 12, 1);
    $var14 = array_slice($row4, 13, 1);
    $var15 = array_slice($row4, 14, 1);
    $var16 = array_slice($row4, 15, 1);
    $var17 = array_slice($row4, 16, 1);
    $var18 = array_slice($row4, 17, 1);
    $var19 = array_slice($row4, 18, 1);
    $var20 = array_slice($row4, 19, 1);
    $var21 = array_slice($row4, 20, 1);
    $var22 = array_slice($row4, 21, 1);

    // Insert into database
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(#STN, LAT, LON, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm2, WDIR, WSPD,     GST, WVHT, DPD, APD, MWD, PRES, PTDY, ATMP, WTMP, DEWP, VIS, TIDE)
    VALUES ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8, $var9, $var10,   $var11, $var12, $var13, $var14, $var15, $var16, $var17, $var18, $var19, $var20, $var21,
    $var22)");

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Sorry I am new to PHP and MYSQL. My column names in my MYSQL database are the same as what appears in the ()'s of table1(), and they are set to "text" as the type. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: fgetcsv() with a space delimiter would make this so much easier.

Comment: If you ever find yourself using $var1-22, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to quote your vars
As in `VALUES ('$var1', '$var2' ....)`

By the way, I suggest you clean your code a little bit.
Creating `$var{1-22}` is going to be a nightmare to mantain.
You could use the implode function instead of creating 22 variables

I dont know, perhaps in this way?

```
echo 'VALUES (\'' . implode('\',\'', $row) . '\')';
```

Also, im not sure if Mysql allows columns with `#` on its name. Take a look at that your `#STDN` column and check if that is allowed.

Take into account the following:

- Please Consider switching to [PDO](http://co.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://co.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). If you were using ***PDO*** this problem would have a very easy solution.
- If you want to stick to mysql_* functions, at least sanitize all the data you are going to insert in your database with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it with echoing your sql syntaxt in browser:

```
echo "INSERT INTO table1(#STN, LAT, LON, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm2, WDIR, WSPD,     GST, WVHT, DPD, APD, MWD, PRES, PTDY, ATMP, WTMP, DEWP, VIS, TIDE)
VALUES ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8, $var9, $var10,   $var11, $var12, $var13, $var14, $var15, $var16, $var17, $var18, $var19, $var20, $var21,
$var22)";
```

Copy the echo result and execute it on mysql. See whats happen.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer the title, which may also help you solve your issue. You can slice your array into another array to get only the values you want to insert.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table1(STN, LAT, LON, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm2, WDIR, WSPD,     GST, WVHT, DPD, APD, MWD, PRES, PTDY, ATMP, WTMP, DEWP, VIS, TIDE)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')
$sth->execute(array())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your varables in code like '$var1' and in end of do die(mysql_error) like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(#STN, LAT, LON, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm2, WDIR, WSPD,     GST, WVHT, DPD, APD, MWD, PRES, PTDY, ATMP, WTMP, DEWP, VIS, TIDE)
    VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3', '$var4', '$var5', '$var6', '$var7', '$var8', '$var9', '$var10',   '$var11', '$var12', '$var13', '$var14', '$var15', '$var16', '$var17', '$var18', '$var19', '$var20', '$var21',
   '$var22')") or die(mysql_error());
```

What mysql_error does is check and report errors in your statement. If got any, post them here to let us resolve it. And you sure you are connectign to the database??